# Find out which user accessed a particular file on what time in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix

can someone suggest me any command that i can use to see which user accessed a particular file on what time in UNIX. I know history command lists the commands fired previously, but it doesn't include "who" fired it and on what time.

Comment: You can log the history time by means of `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environment variable. See `man history`. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144845/how-would-you-get-all-users-history

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov do you have a man page for `history`? I'm on Arch Linux and I have not. For me it is a builtin of `bash` or `zsh`.

Comment: @Lucas, `man history` opens `BASH_BUILTINS(1)` man page for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use Linux `auditd` for a particular file

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

**Example**

Let say I have a file (let it be `$HOME/an_important_file.txt`) and I want to watch all accesses to it. First set up audit rule for it:

```
$ sudo auditctl -w $PWD/an_important_file.txt -p warx -k watch_an_important_file
```

And checked the audit log:

```
$ sudo ausearch -k watch_an_important_file
----
time->Thu May 12 10:54:16 2016
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1463039656.913:278): auid=500 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:auditctl_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 op="add rule" key="watch_an_important_file" list=4 res=1
```

Then I modified the file with touch (`$ touch $HOME/an_important_file.txt`). I am checking again the audit log:

```
$ sudo ausearch -k watch_an_important_file
----
time->Thu May 12 10:54:16 2016
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1463039656.913:278): auid=500 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:auditctl_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 op="add rule" key="watch_an_important_file" list=4 res=1
----
time->Thu May 12 10:56:42 2016
type=PATH msg=audit(1463039802.788:291): item=1 name=(null) inode=535849 dev=fd:02 mode=0100664 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 nametype=NORMAL
type=PATH msg=audit(1463039802.788:291): item=0 name="/home/Sergey.Kurenkov/" inode=524289 dev=fd:02 mode=040700 ouid=500 ogid=500 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 nametype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(1463039802.788:291):  cwd="/usr"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1463039802.788:291): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7fff6d986060 a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=3149b8f14c items=2 ppid=4852 pid=10022 auid=500 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fsgid=500 tty=pts1 ses=1 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="watch_an_important_file"
```

Comment: Definitely preferable over [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37157226/171318)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` to find out when a file was last accessed. This is only possible if your file system stores the `atime` of inodes. But this does not tell you who accessed the file.

You can use `lsof` to list processes which *currently* use a file. But you might not see processes of other users if your user has insufficient privileges (you can see all processes if you are root).

Normally the output of `history` is generated from a history file of the executing user. So you can assume that the commands printed by `history` where all executed by the same user. In some shells you can set an option in order to store the time of execution together with the command. Then you can also get this time with `history`. This might depend on the shell you are using.

You can read the man pages of `stat`, `lsof`, `bash` or `zsh` (or maybe `ksh`?) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add these following lines in `~/.bashrc` so that now `history` command
logs the commands in the `[<user> 2016-05-11 14:04:33] <command>` format. The below commands apply to all open interactive terminals.

```
export HISTFILESIZE=100000000     
export HISTSIZE=100000000

# First two are optional, they need to be changed only if the default 500
# lines history logging needs to be changed

export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[$USER %F %T] "
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Original [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/bash-history-ignoredups-and-erasedups-setting-conflict-with-common-history) with modification done to store the `$USER`

Comment: This can be put in `/etc/bash.bashrc` so that it applies to all users.